# Movie where people are in bunkers and one of them goes mad

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, thriller

I remember watching a trailer for this particular movie but cannot seem to find it anywhere. I'm looking mainly because it is driving me crazy I cannot remember the name.

Here are the details from the trailer: It was about a group of people who live in personalized bomb shelters/bunkers/something of the sort and they are able to communicate with others in similar built shelters. After communicating for sometime they notice one of the guys is not right.

That's most of what I can remember. I've tried my best to find the movie on my own, hoping someone might have an idea of what this movie is. I'm pretty sure it was to be released sometime in 2016 or 2017.

Edit:

Some more detail to the the movie I'm looking for is each person is isolated in their own bunker, like a company made or supplied them for each individual person. They then have a TV screen and are able to communicate with other bunkers and the individual person in each bunker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [Domain](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4694518/combined) that came out in 2016 (in select theaters).

> After a deadly virus wipes out most of humanity, the survivors are forced to wait alone in self-sustaining bunkers while the viral threat runs its course. Able to communicate through a networked video interface, the survivors wait for years and slowly become a motley family of sorts. But their fragile social ecosystem is shattered when, one by one, they start mysteriously disappearing from their bunkers.

One (or more) of them do seem to go mad. Here's the trailer:

Answer (score 1):

That could the the Outer Limits episode [Dead Man's Switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Man's_Switch_(The_Outer_Limits)), (1997).

> After arriving at the bunker, Ben is told by General James Eiger that
>   the Hubble Space Telescope has photographed a fleet of alien ships
>   heading towards Earth. Fearing the worst, the world's chemical,
>   nuclear, and biological weapons stockpiles were linked to create a
>   single doomsday weapon. **Five people**, including Ben, **are placed in five
>   United Nations Strategic Air Command bunkers** around the world (United
>   States, Russia, China, South Africa, and Australia), with the mission
>   of controlling the activation of a final revenge weapon should the
>   aliens turn out to be hostile and attempt to take over.

The episode is available [on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJmIq_UtNVs).

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like [10 Cloverfield Lane](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1179933/). I haven't seen the film (yet) but the trailer definitely matches your description.

Comment: It's not actually. That comes up when I search, but I've already seen that movie. Thank you though.

Comment: There's only the one shelter in *10 Cloverfield Lane* (vs communication amongst shelters).

Comment: I am aware of that, but there are different rooms shown in the trailer (IIRC) so someone not paying attention could get the impression there was more than one shelter being shown.

Comment: The movie I'm looking for is each person is isolated in their own bunker, like a company made or supplied them for each individual person. They then have a TV screen and are able to communicate with other bunkers and the individual person in each bunker.